# Can this SQL query be simplified without the CTE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm not a SQL developer. I have this code below that my DBA wants me to simplify further. Hoping you guys can take a look and help how to simplify this query further.  Is it possible to not use CTE here? Thanks.

```
 ;     
 WITH CTE_tmp1(RecId, Newdata, Changecode) AS       
 (  
    SELECT RecId, Newdata, Changecode
       FROM dbo.POLL
       WHERE Changecode = 1
 )
UPDATE dbo.POLL
     SET  RecId = T.Newdata
     FROM  dbo.POLL  P
     INNER JOIN CTE_tmp1  T
       ON  P.RecId = T.RecId
     WHERE P.Changecode IS NOT NULL AND P.Changecode <> 1
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need the CTE.
Use a self join of the table `POLL` in the `UPDATE` statement.
Also the condition:

```
P.Changecode IS NOT NULL
```

is not needed since you have:

```
P.Changecode <> 1
```

which will filter out `null`s.

```
UPDATE P
SET P.RecId = T.Newdata
FROM POLL P INNER JOIN POLL T
ON P.RecId = T.RecId
WHERE P.Changecode <> 1 AND T.Changecode = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas!  This is great.